# Bootstrap 3 remote modal form submit preventDefault not working

Tags: html, jquery, coffeescript

I have a challenge executing successfully a `preventDefault()` in *Bootstrap 3*; the issue is that the `preventDefault()` doesn't work as expected for a reason I can't identify.

Below is my code:

index.html:

```
<div class="container">
    <li>
        <a href="/stc/modalRemote.html" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalDefault">
            <b class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></b>
        </a>
    </li>
    <div id="modalDefault" class="modal fade"></div>
</div>
```

modalRemote.html:

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">plus/h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputPlus" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Plus</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputPlus" placeholder="Plus">
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                        <button type="submit" id="btnPlus" class="btn btn-default">Plus</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

index.coffee: (compiled to index.js)

```
$('form').submit (e)->
  e.preventDefault()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue in a remote modal form and solved it by adding e.stopPropagation().

```
$('form').submit (e)->
  e.preventDefault()
  e.stopPropagation()
```